# parent data display with child count

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database `tbl_products`

```
id   parent_id  product_name 
1       0           abc
2       1           xyz
3       1           fgh 
4       1           pqr
5       2           lmn
6       2           uvw
```

I want to display data like

```
id   child_count  product_name 
1       3           abc
2       2           xyz
3       0           fgh 
4       0           pqr
5       0           lmn
6       0           uvw
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following query:

```
SELECT id,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM tbl_products
        WHERE parent_id = t.id) AS child_count,
        product_name
FROM tbl_products AS t
```

The query uses a correlated subquery to get the number of children of the current record.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8ff35/3)

Alternatively you can use a `JOIN`:

```
SELECT t1.id,
       COALESCE(t2.cnt,0) AS child_count,
       t1.product_name
FROM tbl_products AS t1        
LEFT JOIN (SELECT parent_id, COUNT(*) AS cnt
      FROM tbl_products
      GROUP BY parent_id
) AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.parent_id
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8ff35/6)

Comment: @abhayendra Glad I was able to help. Please mark this, or any other, answer as accepted if it helped you solve your problem.